# TableForm for list of calculation

Tags: list-manipulation

Here is my input:

```
EQN[t_, M_] := 3 M + 6 t^2/(30 M);
t0 = 50;
ff = EQN[t0, M];
i = {3, 7, 10, 16};
TableForm[Table[{ff, PaddedForm[N[EQN[t0, i]], {20, 10}]}, {ff, i}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{}, {"M", "EQN"}}, TableSpacing -> {1, 1}]
```

Output:

[image]

But i want the result of `EQN` and `M` in the same row, and able to specify how many digits of `EQN` with `PaddedForm`. Seems like i mistakenly put the whole result in one row and repeated on each row. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Bill still don't understand (sorry). Now i get error "Non-list iterator `N[EQN[t0, i]]` at position `2` does not evaluate to a real numeric value".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the bug is `EQN[t0, i]` Should it read `EQN[t0, ff]`?  Then you get:

```
EQN[t_, M_] := 3 M + 6 t^2/(30 M);
t0 = 50;
ff = EQN[t0, M];
i = {3, 7, 10, 16};
TableForm[Table[{ff, PaddedForm[N[EQN[t0, ff]], {20, 10}]}, {ff, i}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{}, {"M", "EQN"}}, TableSpacing -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]